# How to get md-content to scroll within a form?

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material

Below is the layout of a screen in my application. I am unable to get the md-content to scroll. Instead the entire page scrolls. Any suggestions?

`

```
<form name="myForm">
  <!-- Header Area-->
  <div>
   <label>Header</label>
   <md-button type="submit" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">Submit</md-button>
  </div>
  <!-- Content Area-->
  <md-content>
    <!-- Form fields-->
  </md-content>
</form>
```

`

I tried setting the form's overflow to hidden and explicitly setting the md-content's overflow to auto but that doesn't help.

Below is the plunker i created which demonstrates the entire page scrolling instead of md-content.

http://plnkr.co/edit/YWr30m2sTci7rdIbFFzM?p=preview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing your form element to: `<form name="myForm" flex layout="column" style="overflow: auto; height: 100%;">`

seems to do the trick.

http://plnkr.co/edit/pKwFGmkJmhifdyqCg9aU?p=preview

Comment: I used layout-fill instead of style="overflow:auto; height:100%" and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Mike Feltman's solution works, but all that you really need is to apply `layout` attribute (`layout="column"` in your case) to your `form`.

Check this one:
http://plnkr.co/edit/BCtIw951qSnsHbyU69a6?p=preview

Comment: In my app, I also had to use a layout-fill for md-content to scroll. Thank you!